# Angular2 does not load (error)

Tags: angular, typescript

I dont understand,what is the error, because i dont edit my code,before that everything worked. The compiler successfully compiles. I use Angular cli.
Does not show the page, show only Loading..., but in console error 
[image]
      Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

I cant find any resource to solve this problem. I cleared my browser's cache.I looked all the codes like everything is OK.

Comment: Can you explain the steps you took please? Or show the code you have.

Comment: @Edgar The application worked fine, I did not change anything in the code, I suddenly got this error.

Comment: Do you know where the apply is being called?

Comment: @Edgar it is not in my code. It is in intl.js                                                   function combine(options) {
    return (_a = ((Object))).assign.apply(_a, [{}].concat(options));
    var _a;
}

Comment: check in firefox, does it works ?
I bet it works in firefox and not chrome & IE

Comment: @ParthGhiya Yes it`s work in firefox. Thank you. But in Chrome how solve  it problem.

Comment: How do you import Intl.js? Is it via cdn? Maybe they released a Broken version.

Answer (score 2):

There seems change in either Angular CLI Version/ NPM / Node JS.

Any of the following things should work.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4632

1. Upgrade Angular CLI, remove node_modules, install those again.
2. Upgrade NPM and node JS
3. Upgrade Chrome Browser as per gitHub issue Link.

Last thing you can do is.
use intl polyfill.

```
npm i mdn-polyfills --save
```

To use this

```
import 'mdn-polyfills/Object.assign'
```